# Powershell Script to find URL's on content pages, lists and libraries that point to a specific url in SharePoint 2010

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I'm trying to search through SharePoint 2010 to find links that point to a broken URL using PowerShell.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: you probably need some regex in powershell or C# to filter the hyper links in the html content.

Comment: I need an idea where to begin code wise.

Comment: when you say content pages, lists and libraries . Does it mean the list item fields or the content inside the documents ?

Comment: Great question. It can be any SharePoint object. List item, Doc Library, Web part, content page or document.

Comment: I had done ps script to scan all page content field ,SummaryLinksField ,summary links wp ,content editor wp ,script editors to fix broken links in my SharePoint Online Site. Is that something you are after ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should allow you to search within content pages for a specific string, such as a given URL.

```
param(
    $webUrl = "http://dev:8081",
    $urlToFind = "mylink.domain.com/"
)

clear-host

$web = get-spweb $webUrl

$list = $web.Lists["Pages"]

foreach($item in $list.Items)
{
    write-host ""
    write-host "*** PAGE *** "$item.Url
    write-host ""
    $file = $item.File

    #get binary data, and decode into text
    $data   = $file.OpenBinary()
    $encode = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
    $text   = $encode.GetString($data)

    if($text -match $urlToFind)
    {
        write-warning "FOUND BAD URL IN THIS DOCUMENT!"
    }

    write-host ""

    #comment below to parse all pages
    #break

}
```

If you're looking for something more robust, you can actually identify all the URLs on each page and even make an HTTP request to check if the URL exists.

```
param(
    $url = "http://dev:8081"
)

clear-host

#region URL Tester
function QueryLink($webUrl)
{
    #test positive
    #$webUrl = "http://www.google.com"

    write-host ("Querying domain '" + $webUrl + "'..." + $nl)

    $result = MakeHttpRequest $webUrl
    if($result -eq $true)
    {
        write-host ("The url '" + $webUrl + "' exists." + $nl)
    }
    else
    {
        write-error ("The url '" + $webUrl + "' does not exist. Status: " + $result + $nl)
    }

}

function MakeHttpRequest($url)
{
    # First we create the request.
    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)

    # We then get a response from the site.
    try
    {
        $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
    }
    catch
    {
        return $false
    }

    # We then get the HTTP code as an integer.
    $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

    If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) { 
        return $true
    }
    Else {
        $HTTP_Status
    }

    # Finally, we clean up the http request by closing it.
    $HTTP_Response.Close()
}




#endregion

function FindUrlInText($text)
{
    #reg credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259203/regex-to-match-url-in-powershell
    $results = [regex]::Matches($text, "(http[s]?|[s]?ftp[s]?)(:\/\/)([^\s,]+)")
    foreach($result in $results)
    {
        write-host ""
        write-warning "Found URL:"
        write-host $result.Value
        write-host ""
        write-host "Testing URL..."
        QueryLink $result.Value
    }
}

#lets work

$web = get-spweb $url

$list = $web.Lists["Pages"]

foreach($item in $list.Items)
{
    write-host "*** PAGE *** "$item.Url
    $file = $item.File

    #get binary data, and decode into text
    $data   = $file.OpenBinary()
    $encode = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
    $text   = $encode.GetString($data)

    FindUrlInText $text

    #comment below to parse all pages
    break

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that might (partly) help you on the way. Partly because it only works for pages in the pages libraries across your farm.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing") | out-null
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | Get-SPWeb -Limit ALL | % {
    if ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::IsPublishingWeb($_)) {
        $pWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($_)
        Write-Host "Processing SPWeb $($pWeb.Url)"
        $pWeb.PagesList.Items | % {
            Write-Host " Processing Page $($_['FileRef'])"
            $_.ForwardLinks | ? { $_.Url.IndexOf("~") -eq -1 } | % {
                $url = $_.Url

                try {
                    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
                    $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
                    $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
                    if ($HTTP_Status -ne 200) { 
                        Write-Host "$url appears to be broken ($HTTP_Status)" -ForegroundColor Red
                    } else {
                        Write-Host "$url appears to be OK ($HTTP_Status)" -ForegroundColor Green
                    }
                } catch {
                    Write-Host "$url appears to be broken (Exception)" -ForegroundColor Red
                } finally {
                    if ($HTTP_Response) {
                        $HTTP_Response.Close()
                    }
                }
            }
            Write-Host
        }
        Write-Host "-------------"
    }
}
```